# plotting the stair step plot and extract continuous values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I have discrete x and y axis data as

```
y=[14.0,11.0,14.0,31.0]
x=[3.45,3.88,3.99,4.33]
```

I need to plot the figure as depicted below.

[image: plot]

Finally i want to extract continuous red line values.
I tried using the code below but it doesnot give the expected result.Hope experts may help me.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y=[14.0,11.0,14.0,0.0]
x=[3.45,3.88,3.99,4.33]
plt.step(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: on x-axis is the thickness and y axis is the temperature value

Comment: how 4.33= X made somethings more than  60  ?

Comment: sorry i updated the right x and y axis values

Comment: I don't understand what do you want to do?

Comment: @Corralien, after plotting x and y values the plot should look like as given  then i want to extract the continuous red line values wrt y axis

Comment: So What's wrong with your plot? Get continuous values is not so complicated.

Comment: Sir i am unable to plot using my values

Comment: i think the given data is still wrong. e.x look at 3.88 saying 11 but in the picture it's around 25.

Comment: maybe they are sum up together ?

Comment: @AminS is right. y_cumsum gives [14., 25., 39., 70.]

Comment: pro, Can you answer to @AminS about sum, please?

Comment: @AminS its the addition of 14.0,11.0

Comment: @Corralien i answered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get continuous values, use `interp1d` from `scipy`:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.array([3.45, 3.88, 3.99, 4.33])
y = np.array([14.0, 11.0, 14.0, 31.0])
y = np.cumsum(y) # ???
y0 = np.array([0])
x0 = np.interp([0], y, x)
x = np.concatenate([x0, x])
y = np.concatenate([y0, y])

# Continuous data
NUM = 1000  # modify the number of points you want
funct = interp1d(x, y, kind='next')
x_cont = np.linspace(x[0], x[-1], NUM)
y_cont = funct(x_cont)

# Plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.step(x_cont, y_cont, color='r', label='test.mod', where='post')
ax.set_xlim(2, 5)
ax.set_ylim(0, y.max())
ax.invert_yaxis()
plt.show()
```

Output:

```
>>> x_cont
array([3.45      , 3.54777778, 3.64555556, 3.74333333, 3.84111111,
       3.93888889, 4.03666667, 4.13444444, 4.23222222, 4.33      ])

>>> y_cont
array([ 0., 25., 25., 25., 25., 39., 70., 70., 70., 70.])
```

[image]

Comment: @pro. Continuous data doesn't mean much, you can upsampling your data. Did you try my answer?

Comment: how to plot the same plot using ur data

Comment: can u plz suggest a solution

Comment: no i am unable to bring the same plot

Comment: the plot is different. If you check the code of M472 it gives nice plot

Comment: after interpolation also should i get the same plot or not ??

Comment: After interpolation, you will have the same plot, you have just more point. I updated my answer, can you check it please?

Comment: ax.step(x_cont, y_cont, color='r', label='test.mod', where='post') doesnot give same plot

Comment: u r not using x_cont and y_cont in the step plot, instead u r using x and y

Comment: can u plz update the answer so that i can increase the data points  and will get the same plot using interpolated values

Comment: i am waiting for your updated answer

Comment: It doesn't change anything, except for y=0 because x is undifferentiated from y=0 to y=14 so the interpolation doesn't work in this interval. Does my answer solve your problem now?

Comment: no, it doesnot give the same plot

Comment: Do you understand my explanation? It's not possible on this interval, For x=[0, 3.45], y=14

Comment: ok...should i ask another question

Comment: can we do something like this  def interp(y):
    x=np.linspace(0, 3, 4)
    cs = interp1d(x, y,kind='cubic')
    xs = np.linspace(0,4,1000)
    ys=cs(xs)
    return ys

Comment: Fix with `def interp(y): x=np.linspace(0, 3, len(y)) cs = interp1d(x, y,kind='cubic') xs = np.linspace(0,3,1000) ys=cs(xs) return ys` but does not return y values but x...

Comment: ok, ohh my god...what to do

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to notice is the x values of the step plot. Matplotlib threats these as absolute values. You also need to add the x-value 3.45 twice for the first vertical segment.

For the vertical segments there is a possibility to set it to 'pre' to draw the vertical line before the point or 'post' for after the point. I chose to set it to 'post'.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [3.45, 3.45, 3.88, 3.99, 4.33]
y = [0.00, 14.0, 25.0, 39.0, 70.0]
plt.step(x, y, 'r', label='test.mod', where='post')

# set range of x-axis
plt.xlim([2.0, 5.0])

# invert y-axis by setting the lower limit to a higher value than the upper limit 
plt.ylim([60, 0])

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: i need continuous data of x and y axis. How do i extract can you please help me on this

Comment: can u plz suggest a solution